# The 'EurekaPackage' package did not load correctly - Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

I installed VS 2013 Premium. On first launch I get this error

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> The 'EurekaPackage' package did not load correctly.
>
> The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the
>   installation of another extension. You can get more information by
>   examining the file
>   '\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
>
> Continue to show this error message? Yes   No

Below a copied from ActivityLog.xml

```
<entry>
    <record>83</record>
    <time>2014/03/14 14:51:59.561</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [File Change Manager Package]</description>
    <guid>{4825B9A3-93E2-4327-9044-41F72EE7E5C9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>84</record>
    <time>2014/03/14 14:51:59.577</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [File Change Manager Package]</description>
    <guid>{4825B9A3-93E2-4327-9044-41F72EE7E5C9}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>85</record>
    <time>2014/03/14 14:53:21.928</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [EurekaPackage]</description>
    <guid>{8C28E535-ABC9-4F92-B5C9-6C16617C8884}</guid>
    <hr>80131509</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot create file mapping.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>86</record>
    <time>2014/03/14 14:53:21.977</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [EurekaPackage]</description>
    <guid>{8C28E535-ABC9-4F92-B5C9-6C16617C8884}</guid>
    <hr>80131509</hr>
    <errorinfo>Cannot create file mapping.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>2462</record>
    <time>2014/03/14 14:56:57.158</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage</description>
    <guid>{ED19932F-5443-4587-A005-1CB9158B2F64}</guid>
  </entry>
```

Answer (score 31):

I got this error in Visual Studio 2017 when trying to load my ASP.NET project. I also got two instances of the error "The PackageManagementPackage did not load correctly" along with the "The 'EurekaPackage' package did not load correctly" error.

Similar to [tandrasz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44172705/12484), I started seeing this error after disabling a bunch of extensions in Visual Studio's `Tools` > `Extensions and Updates` dialog.

I also found that the "Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools" extension had become disabled, even though I hadn't manually disabled it.  Even after manually re-enabling that extension, it would become disabled again each time I restarted Visual Studio while the "package did not load correctly" error persisted.

Doing some science of re-enabling one extension at a time and restarting Visual Studio each time, I found that the specific extension I needed to re-enable to get things working again was the **Microsoft Azure App Services Tools extension** -- even though my project doesn't do anything with Azure.

(I also needed to re-enable the Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools extension along with that Azure extension.)

Comment: Great investigation

Comment: You sir are awesome. I was about to reinstall VS2017 again until a came across your answer. I had disabled "Azure data lake and stream.." and "Azure functions and web jobs tool". Enabling these did the trick, no more errors.

Comment: Ditto - re-enabling "Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools" was the trick for me - in VS 2017.5.

Answer (score 7):

Similar thing happened to me in Visual Studio 2017.

It is working now after **re-enabling extensions that came with Visual Studio** and which I disabled manually, because I thought I didn't need them.

Comment: It also worked for me in VS2017, thank you very much!!

Comment: Tom, to you remember which extensions you re-enabled? I haven't disabled any of the MS ones, just some Resharper ones (ReadyRoll for VS2017 and SQL Prompt Core). I don't see the "Microsoft Azure App Services Tools extension" anywhere in my extensions list.

Comment: @PHenry - it's been a while, try the Resharper ones.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for the reply. But I'm a bit confused, which Resharper ones do you mean? The sql ones? Those are the ones I disabled. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @PHenry, I've looked at my extensions again. Maybe it was some Roslyn extension that I disabled initially. I currently have these (just the key words, partial list) from the VS installation: Developer Analytics, Test Explorer, Test Platform, MSTest, Node.js, Razor, Roslyn, TypeScript, TextMate, Apache Cordova, Interactive Window.

Answer (score 3):

I excluded my computer from receiving domain group policies and it solved the issue. YMMV.

I will start applying group policies one by one until the culprit is found.

I will update this post as soon as I find the offending policy.

Hope it helps.

Luis

Answer (score 2):

This bug is reported on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/808410/the-eurekapackage-package-did-not-load-correctly) but they close it as not reproducible :-(

The newest VS2013 Update 2 RC did not resolved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Running VS with Administrator previleges fix problem.

Comment: I'm having this problem ONLY when I run VS with Administrator privileges

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue in VS2017 and initially deleting the cache file from the directories described above, HOWEVER, I have since found a little software gem written by Mads Kristensen to do this FOR me.

**You can DOWNLOAD it from the "Tools" menu under and "Extensions and Updates" - it's called "Clear MEF Component Cache".**

Install, and voila, you can fix the issue with a click of the "Tools" menu in Visual Studio!

SUPER SIMPLE and no hiking boots required! (for traversing the directory structure)  Thanks Mads!

The Github repo can be found here [Clear MEF Component Cache](https://github.com/madskristensen/ClearComponentCache)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with local permissions on your machine.
Are you the Admin on your machine?
Do you have any software such as PowerBroker installed on your machine (if you are in a corporate environment)?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was [reported](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/872752/the-eurekapackage-package-did-not-load-correctly) and it's fixed in the Update 4 for Visual Studio 2013. Installing this update will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me after installing the Visual Studio 2015 Feb CTP, which was installed side-by-side with Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. Even though I hadn't changed any settings in VS 13, I was told the Eureka package was not loading.

I was able to fix by Repairing VS 2013.

BTW, the 'EurekaPackage' appears to be the *Page Inspector* feature, which is installed in the following location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Page Inspector\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Package.dll
```

You can read more about it here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/using-page-inspector-in-aspnet-mvc

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue so i just created a backup copy of ComponentModelCache file and the deleted the original one.

For VS2013 delete ComponentModelCache from below path-
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache

For VS2012 delete ComponentModelCache from below path -
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache

Answer (score 0):

In my case (VS 2017) I had to enable all Azure extensions:

- "Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics tools"
- "Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools"
- "Service Fabric Tools"

Comment: Although this did remove my messages, I'm concerned that my web projects REQUIRE these to be enabled, even though none of these were used\employed\included\referenced in the projects. I believe these might be accidental fixes to the root cause. I'm going to keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this error, and I just reset the settings.

open the developer command prompt of Visual studio then type: 
**devenv /resetuserdata**

Directory something similar to this:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE`

*-might need to close all instances of visual studio*

[image]